# Drupal разработка JS-скриптов

Tags: drupal, jquery, javascript

При разработке JS скриптов для Drupal-a, встроенная 
jquery, вызывается довольно таки странным способом, свои функции нужно как-бы оборачивать  вот так

```
(function ($) {
....
Ф-я
}) (jQuery);
```

Сам вопрос: Вот есть скрип вызывающий модальное окно с формой:

```
 $(function() {
   $("a[rel]").overlay(function() {
    var wrap = this.getContent().find("div.wrap");
    if (wrap.is(":empty")) {
        wrap.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
       }
   });

});
```

Я оформляю по образу и подобие его с тем что писал выше, но ничего не работает, при этом без drupal-а все нормально работает, а вот когда пытаюсь встроить, то нет.

Собственно вопрос: как нужно правильно оформлять js-скрипты для разработке с drupal?

Comment: причем тут друпал?

Comment: Собственно на хабре был пост о том как писать скрипты для друпала, и собственно просто на страничке это работало, а при внедрении на сайт переставало, при этом и друпал)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`drupal_add_js('path/to/your/js');`

```js
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.yourmodule = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      // $ здесь можно уже знак долларом пользоваться
      $('#mymodule_id', context).change(function () {
        alert('Handler for .change() called.');
      });
    }
  };  
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: спасибо! Пригодилось!